# sampler2D and samplerCube in one shader

Tags: opengl, glsl

I'm trying to use `sampler2D` and `samplerCube` in one shader. I used to do this using `struct` for several `sampler2D`. But now I decided to stop putting them in the `struct` and noticed several features. If I put `sampler2D` into a `struct`, it is sufficient to bind the `samplerCube` 1 time. But if I put `sampler2D` outside the structure, I will have to bind `samplerCube` each time I draw each model. Below I give examples of pseudocode.

`sampler2D` **into** `struct`:

```
uniform samplerCube shadowMaps;
uniform struct Mapping {
    sampler2D ambientMapping;
    sampler2D diffuseMapping;
    sampler2D specularMapping;
    sampler2D normalMapping;
} mapping;
```

C++ pseudocode:

```
// somewhere in init
// samplerCube
glUniform1i(shadow, 4);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE4);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, shadowMapId);

// ...

// drawing models
for (size_t i = 0; i < MODELS_COUNT; i++) {
    glUniform1i(model[i].ambientMapping, 0);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, model[i].texturesIds[0]);

    glUniform1i(model[i].diffuseMapping, 1);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, model[i].texturesIds[1]);
    // analogically for specular and normal

    // model
}
```

`sampler2D` **outside** `struct`:

```
uniform samplerCube shadowMaps;
uniform sampler2D ambientMapping;
uniform sampler2D diffuseMapping;
uniform sampler2D specularMapping;
uniform sampler2D normalMapping;
```

C++ pseudocode:

```
// drawing models
for (size_t i = 0; i < MODELS_COUNT; i++) {
    glUniform1i(model[i].ambientMapping, 0);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, model[i].texturesIds[0]);

    glUniform1i(model[i].diffuseMapping, 1);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, model[i].texturesIds[1]);
    // analogically for specular and normal

    // samplerCube
    glUniform1i(shadow, 4);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE4);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, shadowMapId);

    // model
}
```

Why in the second case I should everytime do `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, shadowMapId)`? And what is the best way to do it? What will be more productive?

Comment: So you have "COUNT" `samplerCube` and 4 `sampler2D`. But it seems you pass texture units the opposite way.

Comment: @Ripi2 edited, deleted `COUNT`